# Windows 10 Insider version updates not installing

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-preview

I have been running Windows 10 since the initial preview version with minimal problems.  However, the last two Insider builds (10565 and the previous version) will not install.  The build shows up in my Windows Update list, but neither "Restart Now" nor scheduled install works properly.

When I check for updates, I get a "Windows update encountered a problem" error with a retry option.  When I retry, the latest Windows Defender update is installed and then the new build displays as available.  It just won't install.

When I try "Restart Now", the machine reboots normally (it doesn't try to install an update), but a dialog box is shown very briefly just as the desktop appears.  I can't make out what the message says, and all three event logs look normal.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [ISO of the Windows 10 Insider Build 10565](http://aka.ms/softwaredownload_win10insider), mount the ISO and and run `setup.exe`. Now select `Upgrade` to upgrade the normal Windows 10 to the latest Preview. Verify in the settings app -> Update that the Insider settings are correctly set and when a new Build gets released check if you now see it.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been avoiding that option, but I may have no other choice.

Comment: This worked.  Hopefully it was a one-time glitch.

Comment: do you now see Build 10576 (http://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/10/29/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10576/) ?

Comment: Build 10565 for now.  Hopefully 10576 will download and install properly.

Comment: are you in the fast ring? can you use your MS account to login to the insider page?

Comment: Yes, fast ring.   10576 installed automatically last night, so I'm good to go.

Comment: nice to hear that your issue is now fixed :)